# How to store exact decimal number without any rounding in python

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

I have a number **-123456789012345678.879** that is parsed from a json file and stored in a dict. In the dict it shows as **-1.23456789012e+17**

I want to get back the original full decimal number and maintain as it is when outputting to file.

```
a=-1.23456789012e+17

print(a)

-1.23456789012e+17
```

So to remove the exponents that python is formatting as I also tried converting to Decimal from the decimal module

```
Decimal(a)

Decimal(-123456789012345680)
```

In both cases python is changing the exact representation of the decimal that I want. I don't want any rounding or altering of my original decimal.

I do not have the option to format the original parsed value as a string aat the moment and need another way to convert the python exponent number back to the original format

Comment: Hi Jimmy, what are you using to store the data? Maybe it is rounded by the database or whatever you are using?

Comment: Have you tried making `a` a string (that is, `a = "-12....678.929"`, and *then* doing `Decimal(a)`? It looks to me like `a` loses its precision the moment you assign it, because floats just aren't precise enough for what you're trying to do. Keeping it in string form until you can get it into a `Decimal` that can handle the precision would alleviate that problem

Comment: Depending on what exactly you are trying to do, the solution you need may change. If you just want to be able to print the value, you might be able to use string formatting to get the precision you need. If you actually need to store the numbers with full precision, you can use the other options available in the `decimal` package.

Comment: `Decimal()` expect string, you try to pass float.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the issue, but keep in mind that Decimal is just a class - it can't do magic on the value passed to it. When you lose precision in a floating-point number, that happens before the `Decimal` call, so the class has no way to restore the lost information.

To avoid this, the Decimal class also allows you to construct the value from a string. This avoids losing precision:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('-123456789012345678.929')
Decimal('-123456789012345678.929')
>>> print(Decimal('-123456789012345678.929'))
-123456789012345678.929
```

For more details, consult the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).